# Unable to get custom headers in react response

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, cors, reactjs-flux

I have frontend running in react + flux +node and backend running in Java.
I am using superagent to post requests from the react action to the backend which is successfully happening and I am trying to send custom headers from backend which is also working fine and getting  sent from the backend to frontend as I can see in the browsers networks(debugging for request and response).However when I try to access the headers in the react action I don't see it.Can someone please guide me how Can I handle this?

The custom header which I want to access is X-Token but I cant see it in the response from superagent in react action.
The react action function looks as below:

```
login(payload) {
        request.post(someurl+'/login')
            .send({
                username: payload.userEmail,
                password: payload.userPassword
                })
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .end(function(err, res){
                if (err || !res.ok) {

                } else {
                    console.log(res.headers) //it doesnt give x-token header.

                }
            });
    }
}
```

Below is my Server js content:

```
var app = express();
app.options('*', cors());

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
app.use(compression());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
         // Website you wish to allow to connect
         res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

         // Request methods you wish to allow
         res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

         // Request headers you wish to allow
         res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Token,Origin,X-Requested-With,content-type");

         // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
         // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
         res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

         // Pass to next layer of middleware
         next();
     });


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.engine('html', consolidate['swig']);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', './views');


 app.use(function(req, res) {
   Router.match({ routes: routes.default, location: req.url }, function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
     if (err) {
       res.status(500).send(err.message)
     } else if (redirectLocation) {
       res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
     } else if (renderProps) {
       var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(Router.RoutingContext, renderProps));
       var page = swig.renderFile('views/index.html', { html: html });
       res.status(200).send(page);
     } else {
       res.status(404).send('Page Not Found')
     }
   });
 });

require('./app/routes/server-route')(app, express);
var server = require('http').createServer(app);


server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about `setHeader` ?

[express documentation](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#setHeaders) api  for header is `setHeaders`.

Comment: @Damiem Leroux Thanks for your reply.But when I saw various example I could see the above way of setting headers.Can you please provide me some example of alternate approach?

Comment: functions to call depends on the version of 'express' you are using. In your case, which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks.The version of express is 4.14.0.Can you please guide me how to resolve the issue.I know we need to configure cors but the above config doesn't work for me.